# Ruby Sequel Querying table and return JSON format

Tags: sql, json, ruby, sequel

I have a report table for each person on each date like this:

```
+-----+------+----------+------+------------+
| id  | name | received | sent | created_on |
+-----+------+----------+------+------------+
| 1   | A    | 1        | 2    | 2018-07-20 |
| 2   | B    | 3        | 4    | 2018-07-20 |
| 3   | C    | 5        | 6    | 2018-07-20 |
| 4   | A    | 1        | 2    | 2018-07-21 |
| 5   | B    | 1        | 2    | 2018-07-21 |
| 6   | C    | 1        | 2    | 2018-07-21 |
| ... | ...  | ...      | ...  | ...        |
+-----+------+----------+------+------------+
```

Given that I need to query the table with a date range including start date and end day, how could I get a result like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": 'A',
    "received": [1 1 ...],
    "sent": [2 2 ...]
  },
  {
    "name": 'B',
    "received": [3 1 ...],
    "sent": [4 2 ...]
  },
  {
    "name": 'C',
    "received": [5 1 ...],
    "sent": [6 2 ...]
  }
]
```

Comment: "Given that I need to query the table with a date range including start date and end day, how could I get a result like this" – You could get it by writing a program which transforms the above SQL result into the above JSON document. If you encounter a problem with this program you have written, you carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, single-step through the code in a debugger, write tests, trace the execution with pen&paper, and if you *still* can't figure out the problem … wait a week or so and then start from the top with …

Comment: … fresh eyes and a fresh mind. Then, and *only* then if you still have problems, you can read up on how to construct a [mcve] and write a narrow, specific, focused question on [so].

Comment: Trying to give some ideas. The table is a text file? Think about CSV. Can you query the database? Think about a gem like Sequel. Up to you. We wait for reading about your code.

Comment: Are you using the Sequel gem? (You have the sequel tag on this question)

Comment: @trueinViso yes I use Sequel gem. I’m quite new to it so I want to know the efficient way to achieve this in Sequel.

Answer (score 0):

```
DB[:reports]
  .select(:name, :received, :sent)
  .where(created_at: (Date.today - 4)..(Date.today))
```

I obviously used an arbitrary date range that you can modify.

This is assuming you have the connection object stored in a constant called `DB`.  You can find more information about querying the database [here](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel/blob/master/doc/querying.rdoc).

If you need more help configuring sequel for use with your database, you can check the gems [documentation](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel).